# Coldfusion CFScript Query with MySQL Assignment Operator

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, assignment-operator, cfml

I want to select `currentrow` as part of my query - I know I can loop over queries and get the `currentrow` variable, but I'm doing a QoQ before I use the rows and I want to keep the original rows, e.g.

```
//Original query
1, Audi
2, BMW
3, Skoda

//QoQ
1, Audi
3, Skoda
```

This is the code I've got:

```
q = new Query( datasource = application.db.comcar );
q.setSQL('
    SELECT make, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS  `rownumber` 
    FROM cars, ( SELECT @rownum :=0 )
    LIMIT 10
');
r = q.execute().getResult();
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
Parameter '=' not found in the list of parameters specified

SQL: SELECT make, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `rownumber` FROM cars, ( SELECT @rownum    :=0 ) LIMIT 10
```

This will work in `cfquery` but I'd like to use it in CFScript. Is there an alternative to using `:=` or some way of escaping this in the query.

Comment: Did you try using just '=' instead of ':='?

Comment: @ScottStroz tried that, got a new flavor of error: `Argument 2 of function Replace cannot be an empty value. The error occurred in /opt/coldfusion9/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/query.cfc: line 136`

Comment: If you look at line 136 of that file, you'll probably see it's still trying to do stuff with named arguments - did you change **all** instances of `:=` with `=` ?

Comment: Also, this is a bug in CF - you should raise it at https://bugbase.adobe.com

Comment: @PeterBoughton Adam already did http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/09/not-obvious-bug-in-querycfc.html

Comment: That'd be [#3326717](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3326717) - since it's logged against CF9 it's not even included in the [list of bugs Adobe haven't bothered looking at](http://feeds.adamcameron.me/cfbugs/untriagedCf10Bugs.cfm), though it has the same status (and the bug still exists in CF10). I have no idea whether voting for the existing bug will have any effect...

Comment: The bug I raised is unrelated to this. In fact if you read either the bug report or my blog article, I observe that the situation I raise was just me being stupid. This situation as per the question, however, is a real issue, and should be raised.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I took out both colons, the query runs but the `rownumber` column is just an empty string.

Comment: @AdamCameron I saw your post while trying to find a solution for this , but as you say it's unrelated. I'll raise a bug with Adobe and I'll put this on the Adobe forum as well.

Comment: I've submitted a bug, [#3581895](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3581895), I'll find a workaround for now and post that up as a solution shortly

Comment: Sorry, didn't read properly - just saw the colon stuff and jumped to the wrong conclusion. :(
Btw, I'm pretty sure your issue still exists in the latest CF10 too - colons are still treated indiscriminately in Query.cfc - so might be worth updating the issue if someone can confirm that.

Comment: I've got a CF10 instance at home, I'll test it on both of those if no one else confirms it before then. I'll check on Railo as well

Comment: @AdamCameron wow, I jumped right over the update block and dove right into the code in the blog, like Peter. *My bad, yo.* I didn't look at the bug report; I'm pretty sure adobe has a bug database just to say they have one.

Comment: So Adobe haven't even verified the bug, I suppose it's too rare for it to come up to be a major problem, especially on an "old" version of CF. Would any of you guys like to propose a workaround so I can accept an answer on this question? I ended up looping over the query and used `queryAddColumn` in the end. It's only about 200 rows to doesn't really add any page load. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug  in Coldfusion. I could change my code to use `cfquery` but I'd rather not mix script and tags in my page.

So my workaround was is as follows:

```
/*
 * based on the existing query 'tmpFields'
 */

// build array of row numbers
arrRowNumbers = [];
cntRowNumbers = tmpFields.recordCount;

for( r = 1; r <= cntRowNumbers; r++ ) {
    arrayAppend( arrRowNumbers, r );
}

// add a new column with the new row number array
queryAddColumn( tmpFields, "fieldNumber", "integer", arrRowNumbers );
```